# MIPS Assembly how to store values to an array?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

I am trying to create a program where I can store up to 8 values in an array and then compare all these values to find the smallest number.  For some reason my loop overwrites the first position in the array every time.  Here's what I have.  I then add 4 to $t1 on the loop so once it goes back around it should store the next integer in the space after that.  I don't see what I'm doing wrong here?

```
    .data
myArray: .space 32
Msg1: .asciiz "Enter an integer: "


.text


main:
 # Print Message
 li $v0, 4
 la $a0, Msg1
 syscall

 # Prompt the user to enter an integer
 li $v0, 5
 syscall

 # Store the first integer in $t0
 move $t0, $v0
 
 # Declare $t1 for the array position that the integer will be stored at
 addi $t1, $zero, 0
 
 # Store the integer in the array
 sw $t0, myArray($t1)
 
 #Add 4 to $t1 so store the next value in the next array position 
 addi $t1, $zero, 4
 
 beq $t0, $zero, Exit
 
 j main



Exit:
     # Declare an exit to the program
     li $v0, 10
     syscall
```

Comment: _"For some reason my loop overwrites the first position in the array every time"_. Of course it will, since you jump back all the way to `main`, thereby resetting `$t1` to 0 again.

Comment: I thought the array is in .data which is outside the loop so it wouldn't overwrite it every time?  Is there a better way of this this?  should I create a separate loop to keep asking the user for inputs?

Comment: `addi $t1, $zero, 0` is within your loop. You need to organize your instructions and labels such that only the instructions that should be repeated are repeated.

Comment: Okay, I will go over this again.  Thank you.  Besides that I need to find a way to compare all 8 values and print out the smallest number.  I can probably create a loop for that too though.

Comment: Sorry, you're having trouble with this.  Let me offer a philosophical approach that hopefully you will see does the job.  The approach is to do mathematical or logical transformations, one little transformation at a time, all the way to assembly language.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's start with a working algorithm in C:

```
int a [] = { /* array elements */ };
int n = /* count of number of elements */;
...

int currMin = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    int next = a[i];       // next array element to check
    if ( next < currMin )  // is it smaller than what we've seen so far?
        currMin = next;    // yes: capture new min value
}
// on exit from the loop currMin holds the min value
```

---

Ok, now we'll make some simple logical transformations on the way to taking this to assembly language.  First, we remove the for loop in favor of the slightly simpler while loop construct.

```
int currMin = 0;
int i = 0;
while ( i < n ) {
    int next = a[i];       // next array element to check
    if ( next < currMin )  // is it smaller than what we've seen so far?
        currMin = next;    // yes: capture new min value
    i++;
}
// on exit from the loop currMin holds the min value
```

---

Next, we'll transform the while loop into assembly's if-goto-label.  (We could work the if-then first instead; the order we transform doesn't matter.)

```
    int currMin = 0;
    int i = 0;
loop1:
    if ( i >= n ) goto endLoop1;
    int next = a[i];       // next array element to check
    if ( next < currMin )  // is it smaller than what we've seen so far?
        currMin = next;    // yes: capture new min value
    i++;
    goto loop1;
endLoop1:
// on exit from the loop currMin holds the min value
```

---

Next, we'll do the if-then statement.  We could have done it first, that wouldn't change the analysis or results.

```
    int currMin = 0;
    int i = 0;
loop1:
    if ( i >= n ) goto endLoop1;
    int next = a[i];       // next array element to check
    if ( next >= currMin ) goto endIf1;
    currMin = next;    // yes: capture new min value
endIf1:
    i++;
    goto loop1;
endLoop1:
```

---

Next we'll take this to assembly language.

First, assign variables to physical storage, here good choice is registers.  Mental map:

```
$a0 array a
$a1 element count n

$v0 currMin, the result

$t0 loop control variable i, also used as index
$t1 temporary variable "next"
```

Second, translate code as per the last above:

```
    li $v0, 0   # currMin = 0
    li $t0, 0   # i = 0

loop1:
    bge $t0, $a1, endLoop1

    # array reference, variable index: a[i], capture in "next"/$t1
    sll $t9, $t0, 2
    add $t9, $a0, $t9
    lw $t1, 0($t9)

    # the if-then inside the loop body    
    bge $t1, $v0, endIf1
    move $v0, $t1         # capture newly seen lowest value
endIf1:

    # finish the rest of the while loop, having the for-loop i++ here
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    j loop1
endLoop1:
```

---

All that's left is to put some starting and ending code around that, assuming the register numbers match up.

The starting code for this would put the address of the array into `$a0`, and the count of elements into `$a1`.  Could use different registers of course, with appropriate modifications.

The ending code should expect the result in `$v0`, to print or otherwise.

The starting code would be entirely before this code, and the ending code entirely after.

---

Yes, there are a few steps — but each one is a relatively simple and logical transformation.  Logical transformations enable translating the C code, first staying in C but simplifying to make it easy to go right to assembly.

1. Remove for loops in favor of while loops.
2. Change all control structures into if-goto-label
   Each control structure (if, while) can be changed one at a time, stay in C, and keep checking that the code continues to work in C!  Order of control structure transformations doesn't matter (inside out, outside in).
3. Translate simplified C code into assembly:
   a. Map logical variables of C into physical storage of machine code
   b. Convert statements & expressions from C into assembly language

Comment: Thank you.  I'll go through this and declare the variables for $a1 and what not above and test it will.  Will be backed soon once I have it all set up and tested to give you a green check mark.  I see how the C code helps, I just haven't used C yet so I may be best writing things down as pseudo code.

Comment: It doesn't have to be C pseudo code, Java would work, too, for this: at least the initial algorithm would be entirely the same; this because the C I proposed uses array indexing instead of pointers.  Java doesn't have pointers, so if you want to go pointers, C would be a more natural choice.  Pointers are sometimes more efficient and actually easier to use (less assembly code) but have a learning curve.

Comment: Shouldn't the code look like this? https://pastebin.com/5RpytjSq  Just declare the top variables as temps?  Getting output "1" each time

Comment: Never mind.  Just paid for an expert answer on course hero and makes more sense now.  Got it working.  Thanks for trying to help though.